# Unable to sign into Facebook from Android application for some accounts - Invalid application id

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Android app that handles single sign-on with Facebook and requests the following permissions on login: `read_stream`, `user_likes`

I made sure to make my Facebook application public such that it is NOT in sandbox mode, but I still get the following error when logging in for only some accounts:

```
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095): Exception during service
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid application MY_VALID_APP_ID
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:78)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:107)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:291)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:266)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:27)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:157)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:366)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:259)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:245)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:51)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:191)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at com.facebook.common.executors.HandlerExecutorServiceImpl$ListenableScheduledFuture.run(HandlerExecutorServiceImpl.java:268)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 12:00:01.264: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(5095):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095): Failed to send
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095): com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:637)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:46)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation$2.run(BlueServiceOperation.java:602)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-14 12:00:01.298: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(5095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 12:00:01.475: W/InputMethodManagerService(732): Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41b99b70 (uid=10085 pid=4961)
```

I can also confirm that I am setting the correct Facebook Application id in my Android app as well. I also set the required key hashes for my Android app too. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the Facebook App ID meta data in your manifest (or it's pointing to the wrong ID):

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:exported="true"
        android:value="@string/your_facebook_app_id_string" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This field is already in my manifest file and it's the same id. As mentioned, this problem only happens on certain accounts, which is why I am completely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem as you! I use new function 'Test Apps' of Facebook SDK ,
 i found:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Note:

> **Test Apps are always in Development Mode, making it less likely someone may chance upon a pre-release version of your product**

So, I solved the problem by add join team members to testing in Roles.
If you do not have an Test App, you go to "Status and Review" setting to enable "live and available to all users".
I hope to help you, sr my English!